# Google directions; API returns no results

Tags: google-maps-api

I am trying to figure out why my API called to maps.googleapis is returning no results. I inputted my exact same queries into Google Maps (using their interface though, same numbers) and I get directions.

Here is my example:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.4833815,-80.539168&destination=43.47242353,-80.54613339&sensor=true&arrival_time=1417650300000&mode=transit`

Here is the result from google maps:

`https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/'43.4833815,-80.539168'/'43.47242353,-80.54613339'/@43.4780799,-80.5413407,15z/am=t/data=!4m16!4m15!1m3!2m2!1d-80.539168!2d43.4833815!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0x0!2m2!1d-80.5461334!2d43.4724235!2m3!6e5!7e2!8j1417632300!3e3`

Any ideas why this occurring? I am pretty sure my syntax is correct

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of changes needed here to make the api return the correct information
change sensor to false:

incorrect
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.4833815,-80.539168&destination=43.47242353,-80.54613339&sensor=true&arrival_time=1417650300000&mode=transit

correct
and arrival time to departure time.
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.4833815,-80.539168&destination=43.47242353,-80.54613339&sensor=false&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit